# In which method of a UICollectionViewCell should I write code to only run once?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionviewcell

I am looking to modify a `UICollectionView`'s layout just after it has set its `imageView.image`.

I want to know the correct way to execute my code only once for my reusable cell.

So far, the method that works for me was to draw my custom views inside it in the `cellForRow()` method, but it makes the code messy. I would like to execute the code inside the cell's class.

`Init` (with frame) didn't work. It wasn't even called from my `collectionView`.

Moreover, if somebody can give me a fast explanation of what the most important methods of a `UICollectionViewCell` do and when to use each one of them, I would appreciate!

**EDIT:**

This is the code I want to remove from `cellForRow()` and move into the cell's class:

```
firstProductCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "photo1")
firstProductCell.textLabel.text = "Featured title"

let imgview: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1100, 600))
imgview.image = firstProductCell.imageView.image

let whiteView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(1200, 0, 600, 600))
whiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let view: UIView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
view.addSubview(imgview)
view.addSubview(whiteView)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
firstProductCell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: `awakeFromNib`? it's best to show the single run code in the question as it may not actually be appropriate in the cell...

Comment: everything except the last 4 lines seems to just be creatable using the interface builder, no need for code. Why would you want the cell to make the job of populating itself with data, that is the job of the cellForRow method.

Comment: I am not adding the `whiteView` and `imgView` to the cell (to be created in Interface Builder). I am creating those in order to create a combined view of the two and add it as an image. It is important to add it as an image because it benefits from special animations on tvOS. I don't want them created in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't see, how you create your cells, but:
if you register your custom cell class to your collectionView:

```
    collection.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
```

then in the `cellForItemAtIndexpath` you use:

```
let cell : CustomCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
```

then the CustomCollectionViewCell's init with frame method will be called:

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> `awakeFromNib()` method is called only once, so you setup your cell here, like:-

```
class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

       //do some work here that needs to happen only once, you don’t wanna change them later.
    }
}
```